# How can I type cast one SWIG-wrapped C struct from one type to another within Python?

Tags: python, c, casting, swig

I'm using SWIG to make C data structures and functions available to my Python code. I have 2 structures as below -

```
struct A {
  .....
};

struct B {
  struct A a;
  ......
};
```

I call a C function from Python, which returns a `(struct A *) b`, where b is an instance of `struct B`.

Can I type cast the pointer from `struct A *` to `struct B *` within my Python code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but only because the two swig proxies are identical.

There's a layer in between the C objects and the python ones called the proxy layer.